# Redux is giving empty next state

Tags: react-native, redux, saga

Below are the code of Reducers Action and Store .

I am trying to get updated state from the redux store but getting empty state , not sure if reducer has been bind correctly ,tried with other solution but no luck ,

Snippet - https://snack.expo.dev/@shafhadkhan/redux_snippet

Comment: Add code, not the image.

Comment: @Mislah i have added the snippet in this https://snack.expo.dev/@shafhadkhan/redux_snippet